# SQL match if not 0 or > 4

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my issue.

I have 4 tables as example (Shape -> ShapeDetails -> ShapeSize -> ShapeColor)

Basically each time I create a new Shape there is new line ShapeColor created( and for each colors I selected is created new line in the table ShapeColor) Inconvenient I know but the software I have to use has been designed like this.

So , a Shape can have a lot of colors but I would like to match based on the "name" of the color those which have color "red", "pink","blue" BUT if one of them have "red","pink","blue" and "yellow" in this case this one should not be matched.

I would like to match those between 1 and/or 3 colors.
Example (Colors: red,pink,blue,yellow) :

- 0 0 0 0 (none of these colors = NOK) not in the resulstSet
- 1 0 0 0 (only red but not pink blue yellow = OK) Match in the resultSet
- 0 1 0 0 (only pink but not red blue yellow = OK) Match
- 1 1 0 0 (only red pink but not blue and yellow = OK) Match
- 1 0 1 0 ...
- 1 1 1 1 (all of these colors = NOK) not in the resultsSet

btw, I use some joins to get to ShapeColor

I don't know how can I solve this problem with one SQL query, any kind of help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.id
FROM shape s INNER JOIN shape_color sc ON s.id=sc.id
GROUP BY s.id
HAVING 
  SUM(CASE WHEN sc.color='red' OR sc.color='pink' OR sc.color='blue' 1 ELSE 0 END) >0
  AND
  HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN sc.color='yellow' 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

HAVING is applied to grouped results
if sum of valid colors is >0 that means one of the 3 valid colors exists for the shape
if sum of invalid color is >0 thah means yellow color exist

So you get shapes where one (or more) of valid colors exists and invalid color does not exist

UPDATE:

```
SELECT s.id
FROM shape s INNER JOIN shape_color sc ON s.id=sc.id
GROUP BY s.id
HAVING 
  SUM(CASE WHEN sc.color='red' OR sc.color='pink' OR sc.color='blue' OR sc.color='yellow' 1 ELSE 0 END) >0
AND
  SUM(CASE WHEN sc.color='red' OR sc.color='pink' OR sc.color='blue' OR sc.color='yellow' 1 ELSE 0 END) <=3
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution but in my case sometimes yellow can be part of the color. so "red" , "blue" , "yellow" should match also.
Question is more like : If one of these colors (red,pink,blue,yellow) are missing then I want to match the shape. You should have 0 or all this 4 colors otherwise the shape matchs in the resultSet

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the colors are independent, you can do:

```
SELECT sc.shape_id
FROM shape_color sc join
     color c
     ON sc.color_id = c.color_id
WHERE c.color in ('red', 'pink', 'blue', 'yellow')
GROUP BY sc.shape_id
HAVING COUNT(*) < 4;
```

(Your column names aren't clear but you should get the idea.)

By looking in `shape_color`, you are eliminating the first condition -- a color is needed.  This then just checks that there are fewer than 4 colors.  Implicitly, there is at least one, but you could add `HAVING COUNT(*) > 0 AND COUNT(*) < 4`.

Comment: Not sure you understood correctly. Indeed I could do it like this but I could have more then 4 colors I can have 15 as example but I only want to match these which have a group of color where one is missing 

Example : group of color ("red","pink","blue","yellow") if one shape has those 4 colors then the record shouldn't match but if one of those colors is missing then it should match

Comment: @NickyL . . . That is easily accomplished using `where` for filtering before the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

If you find the solution with GROUP BY and HAVING could be confusing, simple first concatenate the colors in a string using LISTAGG.

Note that an `INNER JOIN` is used eliminate the shapes without colors (here 4 - see sample data below).

Also the  `WHERE` predicate  limits only the relevant colors.

```
select s.shape_id,
LISTAGG(c.color, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.color) color_lst
from shape s
join shape_color c
on s.shape_id = c.shape_id
where c.color in ('red', 'pink', 'blue', 'yellow')
group by s.shape_id
;

  SHAPE_ID COLOR_LST                  
---------- ---------------------------
         1 blue,pink,red,yellow         
         2 red                          
         3 blue,pink,yellow
```

You task is than as simple as eliminate the only negative case of all four colors:

```
with colors as (
select s.shape_id,
LISTAGG(c.color, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.color) color_lst
from shape s
join shape_color c
on s.shape_id = c.shape_id
where c.color in ('red', 'pink', 'blue', 'yellow')
group by s.shape_id
)
select shape_id
from colors
where color_lst != 'blue,pink,red,yellow'

  SHAPE_ID
----------
         2 
         3
```

You shoud take some care to check, that the colors within a shape are unique. If not you must add a subquery that distincts the colors within shape. *The same is valid also for the `HAVING` based solutions*.

Sample Data

```
create table shape  as
select 1 shape_id from dual union all
select 2 shape_id from dual union all
select 3 shape_id from dual union all
select 4 shape_id from dual;

create table shape_color as
select 1 shape_id, 'red' color from dual union all
select 1 shape_id, 'pink' color from dual union all
select 1 shape_id, 'blue' color from dual union all
select 1 shape_id, 'yellow' color from dual union all
select 2 shape_id, 'red' color from dual union all
select 3 shape_id, 'pink' color from dual union all
select 3 shape_id, 'blue' color from dual union all
select 3 shape_id, 'yellow' color from dual;
```